# Which AWS S3 Encryption technique provides rotation policy for encryption keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, encryption

In AWS S3 encryption - which technique provides rotation policy for encryption keys?

I am reading recommended is SSE-KMS, but in some places questions where asked like "How does Amazon SSE-S3 key rotation work?"

So which one supports key rotation and if both are supporting key rotation which is recommended?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Amazon SSE-S3 key rotation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126980/how-does-amazon-sse-s3-key-rotation-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of encrypting S3 objects (or putting default encryption on a bucket). Below I only mention server-side encryption (i.e. that performed on the AWS side, not client side):

- SSE-S3 - is free and uses [AWS owned CMKs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#aws-owned-cmk) (CMK = Customer Master Key). The encryption key is owned and managed by AWS, and is shared among many accounts. Its rotation is **automatic** with time that **varies** as shown in the table [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#master_keys). The time is not explicitly defined.
- SSE-KMS - has two flavors:

  - [AWS managed CMK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#aws-managed-cmk). This is free CMK generated only for your account. You can only view it policies and audit usage, but not manage it. **Rotation is automatic** - once per 1095 days (3 years),
  - [Customer managed CMK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#customer-cmk). This uses your own key that you create and can manage. Rotation is **not enabled by default**. But if you enable it, it will be **automatically rotated** every 1 year. This variant can also use an imported key material by you. If you create such key with an imported material, there is **no automated rotation**. Only manual rotation.
- SSE-C - customer provided key. The encryption key is fully managed by you outside of AWS. AWS will not rotate it.

> which is recommended?

It depends. I would say that generally `SSE-S3` is sufficient and it simplifies a lot of operations, e.g. cross-account access to encrypted objects. But due to some external requirements (regulatory issues), other encryption options must be used.

For example, you may be required to rotate encryption key every 6 months. In this case, SSE-S3 nor SSE-KMS with AWS Managed CMK are  applicable, and you have to use KMS with Customer Managed key and [manually rotate](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rotate-keys-customer-managed-kms/) it.